# getElementById returns object, getElementsByName returns none

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code

```
var commentId = 1834;

alert("getElementsByName:: " + typeof(document.getElementsByName("tmp_airDiff" + commentId)[0]));   
alert("getElementById:: " + typeof(document.getElementById("tmp_airDiff" + commentId)));
```

There is no element having `tmp_airDiff1834` as id or name in the document.

Yet here's what I get back:

```
getElementsByName:: undefined
getElementById:: object
```

Could anyone explain why `getElementById` returns `object` when using `typeof`, when there is no such object in the document?

Comment: It looks like you have an element with id = tmp_airDiff1834 but none with that name. Is it the case?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing named tmp_airDiff1834 on the form.

Comment: If there is nothing named like that, so why do you expect this code to return anything different than undefined?

Comment: There is no HTML to show. There is no element by that name.

Comment: Showing that the HTML has no element by that name is equally useful.

Comment: There are around 12000 lines of HTML code :) Don't think that it would make sense to condense it since none of it contains what we are looking for.

Comment: @robotron: Just so you know, `typeof` isn't a function. There's no need for the `()` after it. If you would have simply gotten rid of the `typeof` altogether, and just logged the value, you would have your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confused because

```
typeof null === "object"
```

and `getElementById` returns `null`.

Yes, that's weird, just like `typeof NaN === "number"`, but [that's how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

[image]

In the case of `getElementsByName`, you're outputting the type of `undefined`, which is what you get when you access an element out of an array (or an array-like object, here).

```
[][1] === undefined
```

You wouldn't have felt into this trap with a more adapted debugging practice. Instead of using

```
alert("some name : " + typeof(someValue))
```

you'd better [use the console of your browser](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) :

```
console.log("some name :", someValue)
```

Note that you would have an uniform behavior if testing in `if` :

```
if (document.getElementsByName("tmp_airDiff" + commentId)[0]) {
   // never goes there as undefined is falsy
}
if (document.getElementById("tmp_airDiff" + commentId)) {
   // never goes there as null is falsy
}
```

Comment: And you've made me start using other things besides Notepad++ and alerts. Where's the epic button?!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `document.getElementById()` returns `null` when an element with given ID is not found. And `typeof(null)` returns `object`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `getElementById` returns null if the element is not found and `typeof null` is object
`getElementsByName` returns a collection, if it is empty any index will be undefined `typeof undefined` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `getElementsByName` is returning `undefined` is because it returns an `array`, and you're referencing an index that doesn't exist. As an example:

```
var array = [];
array[2320]; //undefined
array[0]; //undefined
```

`getElementById` on the other hand, returns `null` when the element was not found (it doesn't return an empty array).